# Flutter remove dialogs in sequence

Tags: flutter

I am trying to remove dialogs in a specific sequence but I am getting an following error:

```
E/flutter (14457): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(188)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (14457): Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
E/flutter (14457): At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable. To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling inheritFromWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.
```

Here the sequence:

1. List item
2. Open Confirm dialog 1
3. Close (onPressed) dialog 1
4. Open Loading dialog 2.
5. Close (Navigator.of(context).pop())
6. Open dialog 3 with success message.

Both Dialog 1 and 2 cloese with Navigator.of(context).pop().

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you perhaps creating dialog2 inside dialog1?

Comment: Nope. Create a dialog and closing it one after the other

Answer (score 2):

When you use the function `Navigator.of(context).pop()`,don't use the context from previous dialog,try to use the page's context。
The reason about `Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe` is previous dialog is closed,but you use that dialog's context. You can see the source code:

```
static NavigatorState of(
    BuildContext context, {
      bool rootNavigator = false,
      bool nullOk = false,
    }) {
    final NavigatorState navigator = rootNavigator
        ? context.rootAncestorStateOfType(const TypeMatcher<NavigatorState>())
        : context.ancestorStateOfType(const TypeMatcher<NavigatorState>());// here check the ancestor state,and throw the error
    assert(() {
      if (navigator == null && !nullOk) {
        throw FlutterError(
          'Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.\n'
          'The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a '
          'widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.'
        );
      }
      return true;
    }());
    return navigator;
  }
```